# cloudflare ssl certificate issue

Tags: ssl, cloudflare

Use full mode to connect to websites
But the console will display net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
Unable to get my backend data

I used the certificate and key provided by cloudflare
Don't know if there's anything missing

```
*   Trying 172.67.168.121:443...
```

- ```
  TCP_NODELAY set
  ```
- ```
  Connected to www.phoenixwu.win (172.67.168.121) port 443 (#0)
  ```
- ```
  ALPN, offering h2
  ```
- ```
  ALPN, offering http/1.1
  ```
- ```
  successfully set certificate verify locations:
  ```
- ```
  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crtCApath: /etc/ssl/certs
  ```
- ```
  TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
  ```
- ```
  TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
  ```
- ```
  TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
  ```
- ```
  TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
  ```
- ```
  TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
  ```
- ```
  TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
  ```
- ```
  TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
  ```
- ```
  TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
  ```
- ```
  SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
  ```
- ```
  ALPN, server accepted to use h2
  ```
- ```
  Server certificate:
  ```
- ```
  subject: CN=phoenixwu.win
  ```
- ```
  start date: Nov 10 01:24:34 2023 GMT
  ```
- ```
  expire date: Feb  8 01:24:33 2024 GMT
  ```
- ```
  subjectAltName: host "www.phoenixwu.win" matched cert's "*.phoenixwu.win"
  ```
- ```
  issuer: C=US; O=Google Trust Services LLC; CN=GTS CA 1P5
  ```
- ```
  SSL certificate verify ok.
  ```
- ```
  Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
  ```
- ```
  Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
  ```
- ```
  Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
  ```
- ```
  Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x55b418d3b0c0)
  ```

> ```
> GET / HTTP/2Host: www.phoenixwu.winuser-agent: curl/7.68.0accept: /
> ```

- ```
  TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
  ```
- ```
  TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
  ```
- ```
  old SSL session ID is stale, removing
  ```
- ```
  Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 100)!< HTTP/2 200< date: Tue, 12 Dec 2023 05:59:22 GMT< content-type: text/html< last-modified: Tue, 12 Dec 2023 01:42:16 GMT< cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC< report-to: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https://a.nel.cloudflare.com/report/v3?s=SznBfvf45degL4z9eM%2F4DikKiXiJV2UkDlCbm8vCJzXnOiLMjbvkSX5LK5DMGSAMDHufKG%2FFSCKFD4kaUHH%2Btl5Nbs7jmI1EPvMgoU%2FJPgroBR99U8xzMPoxF1%2FYIfgOigKCxA%3D%3D"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}< nel: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}< server: cloudflare< cf-ray: 8343bdae5b5e6ddf-MIA< alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400<<!doctype html>
  ```

```
  * Connection #0 to host www.phoenixwu.win left intact
```

I tried merging the root certificate into the CA certificate
Still no way to solve the problem